# R Time series scatterplot issue

Tags: r, plot, statistics, time-series

i'm having some trouble with scatterplots in R. I'm trying to plot two time series but i always obtain a chart that has the year value instad of the pch value i set.
Each series has 120 values.
This is the command:

```
plot(x,y,pch="+",col=heat.colors(120))
```

I get "year_number" instead of "+" on my chart.

Comment: Can you `dput(x)` and `dput(y)` and paste the results in your question?  It is very hard to give any guidance when your question is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `points()` function to plot multiple series. Think of your plot as "canvas" and you are "painting" additional layers with functions.

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)

plot(x, pch="+", ylim=c(min(x,y), max(x,y)), 
     ylab="My Label for Y Axis", xlab="My Label for X Axis",
     main="Main Title of the Graph", col="red")
points(y, col="blue")
```

Comment: Please add a few descriptive words so your answer can pass QA. Thanks